# Magic Square Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, project-euler

> This question has been noted to be close to [a Project Euler question](http://projecteuler.net/problem=166).

Please Help me with this question:Considering a **4*4** magic square ,How many ways are there to fill each square with an integer from 1 to 10, such that the sum of each row and column is the same?The integers can be used multiple times

Comment: This is a tad too close to a Project Euler problem (http://projecteuler.net/problem=166) for my liking...

Comment: @Mike: apart from the trivial difference 1-10 v 0-9, there is also the question of the diagonals

Comment: @henry The diagonals are the only real difference, but I'm guessing a solution to this would probably be about 90% of the problem (I actually haven't solved it myself yet...).

Comment: Please help me to solve this problem.Have anay idea anyone?